# Where should I attach the blower motor leads on a Payne air handler?

Tags: furnace

About 8 months ago my daughter's Payne PF1MNB036000AAAAA air handler quit working. The blower would not come on.  I decided that it needed a new board so since she needed heat I disconnected the blower leads, one yellow and one blue and attached a cord to it to provide 110vac power to the blower making it run all the time.  I then ordered a new board.

I have just now got around to putting in the new board but forgot where I disconnected the yellow and blue motor leads (have female disconnects).  I think the blue one attaches to the black relay on the board but I can't figure out where the yellow one clips onto a male connector.  Help, please.

Comment: That doesn't look like a model number. It also doesn't return search results.

Comment: After removing the As I get a [fan coil](https://www.peirce.com/default.aspx?itemcode=PF1MNB036000&Page=item+detail).

Answer (score 1):

Blue is a speed tap and yellow is common or L2   There should also be a red and black wire coming from the motor that should be capped off unless the motor has been changed. 
A picture of the board and wiring diagram would help. It looks from the very poor wiring diagram I found that the yellow wire would go to K1 and the blue would go to NO but like I said the diagram wasn’t very specific.